# Gaming rig endless boot loop, will not install windows. Will not load usb ISO installer

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I've built a light gaming rig a little over a year ago. Recently it was on and just restarted on its own to the msi splash screen. It started to attempt an automatic repair on its own. Then it just kept restarting and trying to do that over and over.

So I installed another drive and attempted to install windows 7, 8, and 10 with 3 different usb drives and it will not install windows. Just restarts when I try to boot to the usb iso installers. I have got it to boot to the usb a couple times, and the windows installer comes up but before I can do anything with it, it just shuts down and restarts.

I have flashed the bios, and at this point I have replaced the motherboard, ram, and the hard drive all new. Same issue. The only thing left original is the video card, cpu, and power supply. I have an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 and it doesn't have video built in so I cant test the video card since I don't have another, but there is no tarring or pixelating or anything video wise.

I can boot into bios no problem, stay there as long as I want, so if its a bad PSU would this be possible?? I've tried Legacy, UEFI, secure boot is off, everything I can think of. Just always restarts unless I'm in bios. Could this be a PSU issue?

Comment: Often times, the BIOS will have a setting for "what to do when power is lost." You might try setting that to "stay off," so that you can perhaps see if the restart is due to loss of power.

Comment: Yes, it can be the PSU and no, that it shows no problem in the UEFI settings means little to nothing as there's almost no stress with it.

Comment: You might need to elaborate on "just restarts". Do the fans keep spinning or not? Do the status lights stay on or not? If you have a hard time to include any detail, you could also create a short video of a so called restart.